# Python variable is not changing

Tags: python, variables, pyautogui

I have a variable that should be changing that is named "scrolldown". It will not change from 0 but I dont know why. Here is my code. Any help is appreciated. For some reason, whenever python prints the variable "scrolldown" it is always 0 no matter how many times it should have gone through 0 + 1. I have tried changing the variable from int(scrolldown) to scroll down and +1 to + 1 but neither works. The variable is defined at the start as '0' but I don't see why that would be causing issues. Why isnt this variable chaning when the script runs?

```
scrolldownunits = int(903 - 553)
scrolldown = 0
Test2 = True

def movelisting():
        print(scrolldown)
        for i in range(scrolldown):
                scrolldowncalc = scrolldown * int(scrolldownunits) * -1
                pyautogui.scroll(scrolldowncalc)
        pyautogui.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        movelisting1 = 1
        Test2 = False
        listingcheck()


def listingcheck():
    if Test2 == True:
        movelisting1 = 0
        scrolldown = 0
    if movelisting1 != 1:
        pyautogui.moveTo(914, 499)   ##CLICK ON EBAY LISTING
        pyautogui.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('NoClothing.png') != None: ###something not working here
        i = True
        o = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('BackArrow.png')
        print(o)
        p = pyautogui.center(o)
        pyautogui.click(p)
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.moveTo(914, 499)
        time.sleep(2)
        scrolldown = scrolldown +1
        movelisting()
    elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('NoBikes.png') != None: ###SEARCHES FOR THINGS WE DONT WANT
        h = True
        c = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('BackArrow.png')
        d = pyautogui.center(c)
        pyautogui.click(d)
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.moveTo(914, 499)
        time.sleep(2)
        scrolldown = scrolldown +1
        movelisting()
    elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('NoSelections.png') != None:
        g = True
        e = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('BackArrow.png')
        f = pyautogui.center(e)
        pyautogui.click(f)
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.moveTo(914, 499)
        time.sleep(2)
        scrolldown = scrolldown +1
        movelisting()
    listingcheck1 = True  ##USED FOR VAR DELETE
    listingcapture() ###CONTINUES ONTO NEXT STEP
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign to a global inside a function, you need to first let Python know you intend to modify the global. By default when you make the assignment Python will create a new variable in the scope of the function with the same name. Add "global scrolldown" to the top of listingcheck().

Comment: Hey, Thank you a ton. You were the only one willing to help. Cheers.